# How to import a class module (.psm1) in PowerShell 4 (doesn't recognize Using statement)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a class module and I'm forced to use PowerShell 4. It doesn't recognize the "using" keyword as it was introduced in PS5.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: If your module actually contains classes there is no workaround, as those were only introduced in PowerShell 5. You wouldn't be able to import the module even if you worked around the lack of `using module` (by using `Import-Module` directly, for example).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way around this?

### No!

Classes (and the `using ...` directives) were introduced in **Windows PowerShell 5.0** - the parser in previous versions wouldn't know what to do with either keyword.

If you want to retain backwards compatibility with 4.0 you need to *remove all type definitions and using statements* from the module code and leverage either pre-compiled binaries or define your custom types with `Add-Type` at runtime instead.